# How to call a variable from 2 strings in swift

Tags: swift, string, variables, call

Problem: When calling a variable, I'm using a string and a variable, after turning the variable into a string, I can combine the 2 strings to form one string, but, I'm unable to find a way to call a variable with this string.

```
let story1 = "Changed this"

// ... there's more string constants didn't feel like adding them

@IBOutlet weak var topButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var storyTextView: UILabel!

var storyIndex : Int = 1

storyTextView.text = ("story\(storyIndex)")
topButton.setTitle(("story" + "\(storyIndex)1"), for: .normal)
bottomButton.setTitle("story\(storyIndex)", for: .normal)

storyTextView.text = ["story\(storyIndex)"]
```

results in compiling error, any combination with [] doesn't work

I expected the constant string (story1) to be called due to the string being in the ().
This didn't occur (and after loading the app with an override func viewdidload), in all 3 boxes i only got the result of "Story1"

Comment: Don't use separate variables. Use an array. So much simpler.

Comment: Sorry , your  question is not clear to me . I used this code . Its work without any compiling error . Better add a  snap of your ViewController class file .

Comment: Im trying to use a string to call a variable...say a variable is named var, I'm trying to use "var" to get the information inside var. Simple a array is the only option...

Comment: Also, I probably should have looked through the post before posting it, Nahid